# Can not seem to make my pop up to work in IE 7 CSS Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/

In the top right I have two buttons that act as a popup Information and Contact. When pressed in IE 7 I did have the problem where the mask went over the top of the popup blocking it from view. I then realised this was because of the opacity in the CSS so I did a IE 7 style only sheet with this css below:

IE 7 CSS:

```
#mask { 
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)!important";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0)!important;  
    -moz-opacity: 0.0!important; 
    -khtml-opacity: 0.0!important;
    opacity: 0.0!important; 
    display: none; 
}
```

All Browsers CSS:

```
#mask {
display: none;
background: #000; 
position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; 
z-index: 10;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)"; filter: alpha(opacity=75); -moz-opacity: 0.75; -khtml-opacity: 0.75; opacity: 0.75;
width: 100%; height: 100%;
z-index: 999;}

 #popup {
display: none;
width: 60%;
height: auto;
background-image: url(../images/pop_up_bg.jpg);
border-bottom: .4em solid #0a0b0f;
border-right: .4em solid #0a0b0f;
padding: 25px 30px;
position: absolute;
top: 5%;
left: 16%;
z-index: 2000;}
```

Then after canceling out the mask I realised that I couldn't close the popup due to the mask being on top even though the popup z-index is 2000 and the mask is 999. So I don't understand why this is on top of the popup instead of underneath.

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: Its probably because your using position:fixed on the mask.

Comment: please post the code that adds the popup, and the mask to the screen include relevant HTML.

Comment: Alex you seem to be right about the position: fixed; I took it off and it started working fine. however it didn't show a mask on all other browsers. I tried to use all of the other positions attributes for ie 8 down but they didn't seem to work. If there is a way to stop position: fixed; for just ie 8 and 7 then we'll have a fix?

Comment: why do you have `-moz-opacity`, `-khtml-opacity` and `opacity` in an IE7-specific stylesheet? IE7 won't recognise any of those, so if that code is only loaded in IE7 then it's completely pointless.

Comment: Use IE conditional statements and have different rules (different stylesheet) for IE http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Also have a look at this regarding fixed positioning in IE http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html

Comment: Thanks Spudley. Alex I already have a style sheet for that but I don't understand how I can essentially turn off the position: fixed;

Comment: You set it to something different in the IE conditional stylesheet.